# Maximum Number of Stable Solutions for Energy Function

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given the function

\begin{equation}
f(x,y,z) =
  (x y - a_1 )^2
+  [(x - a_2)^2
+2 a_3 (x - a_2)(y - a_4)
+ (y - a_4)^2  + a_5 z^2 ]  .
\end{equation}

Is there a method of finding the maximum number of stable stationary points for all $a_i$, i.e. the maximum number of points that satisfy

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0
\quad,\quad
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0
\quad,\quad
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 0
\quad,\quad
\text{Hessian}(f)>0
\quad,\quad
x, y, z, a_i \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}

for any set of parameters $a_i$